# Django is giving trouble on urls to catch and forward to a view. (slug fields)

Tags: regex, django, django-views

I am currently making `views` called by `slug`s on `django` but I seem to have some troubles on that.

Suppose I have database entries like `de` `ce` `ceiling` (`slug fields`). 
Now when I call, `myapp/ce` or `myapp/de`. It returns the view I want. But when I call `myapp/ceiling`, it returns `404`.

`No sculpture found matching the query`

It catches the url though.

The problem occurs when I use capital letter on the `name` field. The other fields hold `lowercase`.

I failed to understand this behavior.

My code is as follows:

### `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('sculptures.views',
            (r'^$', SculptureListView.as_view()),
            (r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', SculptureDetailView.as_view()),
        )
```

### `views.py`

```
class SculptureDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'sculpture'
    def get_queryset(self):
        sculpture_slug = get_object_or_404(Sculpture, slug__iexact=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return Sculpture.objects.filter(slug=sculpture_slug)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    sculpture_slug = get_object_or_404(Sculpture, slug__iexact=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

Here you're fetching the `Sculpture` object that matches the captured slug.

```
    return Sculpture.objects.filter(slug=sculpture_slug)
```

And then you get the `Sculpture` object whose slug is another `Sculpture` object. I wonder how this even works in some cases :)

Since you have a `DetailView`, you can directly use `get_object()`:

```
class SculptureDetailView(DetailView):
    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Sculpture, slug__iexact=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

Comment: I find the documentation weak sometimes. But the bug occurred when I capitalize any letter of the `name` field of an entry. I will update and leave it there if someone also follows this road. Thanks a lot.